# Analyzing Stock Prices in F#

Tags: f#

My name is Ian. I'm currently working through the "Analyzing Stock Prices" tutorial on www.tryfsharp.org. I'm trying to reproduce their webcontent in Visual Studio 2012 with the appropriate libraries.

**I am having trouble figuring out why my "descriptivestatistics" function in the MathNET library is not working. Snippets below.**

Returned error:

> error FS0041: No overloads match for method 'DescriptiveStatistics'.
>   The available overloads are shown below (or in the Error List window).
>   Possible overload: 'DescriptiveStatistics(data:
>   Collections.Generic.IEnumerable) : unit'. Type constraint
>   mismatch. The type 
>       CsvProvider<...>     is not compatible with type
>       Collections.Generic.IEnumerable     The type 'CsvProvider<...>' is not compatible with the type
>   'Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'. Possible overload:
>   'DescriptiveStatistics(data:
>   Collections.Generic.IEnumerable>) : unit'. Type
>   constraint mismatch. The type 
>       CsvProvider<...>     is not compatible with type
>       Collections.Generic.IEnumerable>     The type 'CsvProvider<...>' is not compatible with the type
>   'Collections.Generic.IEnumerable>'.

The particular code and another possible clue:

//get Stats

let stats = DescriptiveStatistics(msftClosesUsd)

//compute std. dev.

standardDeviation [ for r in msftData.Data -> float r.Close ] //had to add 'float' to r.Close to match type

Note: descriptiveStatistics is located at the very end of the code, and standardDeviation is about midway down. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
// *****************************************************************
// ********************Analyzing Stock Prices***********************
// *****************************************************************

// URL: http://www.tryfsharp.org/Learn/financial-computing#analyzing-stock-prices

#r @"...\FSharp.Data.1.1.5\lib\net40\FSharp.Data.dll"
#load @"...\FSharp.Charting.0.82\FSharp.Charting.fsx"

open FSharp.Data
open FSharp.Charting
open System

// Provides a strongly typed view of the file
type Stocks = CsvProvider<"C:\...\Documents\F#\MSFT.csv">

// Get the stock prices from yahoo on MSFT stock
[<Literal>]
let msftUrl = "http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=MSFT"
let msftData = Stocks.Load(msftUrl)

// **************** Calculating Standard Deviation *****************

let standardDeviation prices = 
    let count = Seq.length prices
    let avg = Seq.average prices
    let squares = [ for p in prices -> (p - avg) * (p - avg) ]
    sqrt ((Seq.sum squares) / (float count)) // Convert count to float to be able to divide into Seq.sum squares 
                                             //"F# does not insert any numberical conversions implicitly" - website

standardDeviation [ for r in msftData.Data -> float r.Close ] //had to add 'float' to r.Close to match type

// **************** Introducing Units of Measure *****************

type [<Measure>] USD
type [<Measure>] EUR

let msftClosesUsd = [ for r in msftData.Data -> float r.Close * 1.0<USD> ] //had to change r.close to float to get this to work
let msft = msftClosesUsd
// Average price in USD
let avg = msftClosesUsd |> Seq.average

// Convert EUR to USD
let euroToUsd eur = eur * 1.30<USD/EUR> // As of 2013-06-29

// Is the average price greater than 25 Euros?
let limit = 25.0<EUR>
if avg > (euroToUsd limit) then printfn("Greater!") // 1.3*25 = 32.5. Type 'avg' to see average. Mine was 29.4802.

let standardDeviationUnits (prices:seq<float<USD>>) = //"Could annotate the argument with seq<float<'u>> allowing for generic units." -URL

    let count = Seq.length prices
    let avg = Seq.average prices
    let squares = [ for p in prices -> (p - avg) * (p - avg) ]
    sqrt ((Seq.sum squares) / (float count))

// Unquote for calc below.
//standardDeviationUnits msftClosesUsd

// Get Math.NET Numerics Library Here: http://numerics.mathdotnet.com/
// Install and continue.
#r  @"...\MathNet.Numerics.2.5.0\lib\net40\MathNet.Numerics.dll"
open MathNet.Numerics.Statistics

//get Stats

let stats = DescriptiveStatistics(msftClosesUsd)
```

Comment: Bold doesn't work in code blocks.  Also, what do you mean doesn't work?  Compile or run time error - be specific?

Comment: Noted on code blocks. Compile time. I running this in a script file in Visual Studio 2012 through F# Interactive. Thanks.

Comment: Also when I say it doesn't work, I mean the desciptiveStatistics function will not return a value, and gives the aforementioned error. Everything else works fine.

Comment: Some guesses - 1. you have some values hanging around from experimentation - if this works `let avg = msftClosesUsd |> Seq.average` that implies `msftClosesUsd` has type `float<USD>`.  2. You need to multiply all elements by `1.0<1/USD>` to get a sequence of double rather than typed doubles.

Comment: Also, it would be helpful to produce a minimal example that produces the error - a large amount of your code appears to be irrelevant to the problem at first glance.

Comment: John, thank you for your help. I will try to be more concise in future posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that `DescriptiveStatistics` does not understand units of measure and so you need to pass it the data without the unit annotations.

The easiest way to do this is to apply `float` conversion function to all elements in your `msftClosedUsd` using `Seq.map` function:

```
let stats = DescriptiveStatistics(Seq.map float msftClosesUsd)
```